# How can i delete a image from destination folder if the form is cancelled?

Tags: php, forms, file, delete-file

I have made a form in which an image has to be uploaded. When I have filled all the inputs in, I send it and then a php file validates the values. If there is something wrong I get back to the form with the values that I filled in before, but if I cancel the edition, the image that I have uploaded is still in the destination folder and I don't know how to delete it.

**insertCategory.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

......

// If a file is uploaded the first time and if it is updated
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'])) {
    $test = false;
    try {
        $test = Categoria::testFile($_FILES['logo']);
        if ($test) {
            $logo = Categoria::uploadFile($_FILES['logo'], '../uploads/logos/');
            if ($_POST['currentLogo'] != null) {
                Categoria::deleteFile($_POST['currentLogo'], '../uploads/logos/');
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $errores[] = 'Logo: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
// Logo is not selected and is the first time that the form is filled in, so $_POST['currentLogo'] has the value of $logo that is null.
// Logo is not selected, so it must be null
} else if($_POST['currentLogo'] == null) {
    $logo = null;
    $errores[] = "El logo es obligatorio, por favor, seleccione una imagen para el logo.";
// Logo is not selected, but it has been selected before, so the logo doesn't change
} else {
    $logo = $_POST['currentLogo'];
}

......

else {
    $logo = null;    
}
```

**form.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="currentLogo" value="<?php echo $logo; ?>" />
</div>

.....

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Logo (*)</label>
<?php if($logo === null) { ?>
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" required>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p><img src="../uploads/logos/<?php echo $logo; ?>"></p>
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">                    
<?php } ?>                    
    <p class="help-block">Logotipo para la categoría</p>
</div>

....

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
    <a href="categorias.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Cancelar</a>
</div>
```

How can I delete the logo file in case of the user cancel de edition/update?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: simply dont more the file out of tmp unless all the other validation passes. If it fails, the user will resend the file when they resubmit the form. If they never resubmit (eg cancel) then the tmp file will get removed during regular php cleanup

Comment: Consider using JavaScript to perform input field validation *before* sending anything. The server-side validation is a second (but important) line of defence. Your cancel button could also invoke a JS function that notifies the server that the form has been cancelled, so that it removes the file, but wouldn't work if the browser is simply closed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have decided to create a temp folder to store every temporal file and every file name will be stored in an array. When all the values will have been validated, move the selected file to the destination directory and delete the other ones just before that the register is saved to the database.